# Prebid setup with bidders which have different currencies

Tags: google-ad-manager, prebid.js, prebid

I have a simple Prebid setup with 2 bidders. I donot use "Send all bids to the ad server" feature. So Prebid works RTB with returning bids and sends the winning bids to Google Ad Manager (GAM) with key/value pairs like:

```
hb_bidder=bidder_A
hb_pb=0.10

hb_bidder=bidder_B
hb_pb=0.20
```

Off course there are line-items defined in GAM with the key/value pairs with those values above.

There is no problem in this setup, if all bidders use same currency.

What if **bidder_A** bids in **USD** and **bidder_B** bid in **TRY**
Line items' currency of  bidder_A were set to USD
Line items' currency of  bidder_B were set to TRY
Note: It's possible to use different currencies in GAM 360)

Scenario:

1 USD = 8 TRY

| Bidder | Bid | Currency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | USD |
| B | 5 | TRY |

In this scenario, bidder B wins which is wrong. Currencies donot affect prebid RTB if I am not wrong. When I checked the GAM request, it verifies me.

When I use **Prebid Currency Module**; it converts USD to TRY (1*8=8) for bidder A, and in this case winner is bidder A which is correct one.
**Prebid Currency Module** fixes the RTB problem but Prebid sends converted bid
**hb_pb=8** (TRY), **hb_bidder=bidder_A** to GAM. In GAM side, line items of **bidder_A** defined with currency USD not TRY. So bid matches wrong line-item.

**"Send all bids to the ad server"** maybe solution but it's needed too much work.

I know, it's very complicated case, what do you suggest to fix problem?

Answer (score 0):

While setting up [Prebid Currency Module](https://docs.prebid.org/dev-docs/modules/currency.html), there's a [configuration parameter](https://docs.prebid.org/dev-docs/modules/currency.html#functions) `adServerCurrency` which should match your ad server (usually GAM) currency setting.

> In GAM side, line items of bidder_A defined with currency USD not TRY. So bid matches wrong line-item.

So in this case, you need to set `adServerCurrency` to `USD` because GAM line items are defined with currency USD.